# Loading content into a div, div element changes, previous still visible

Tags: jquery, html

I am loading data of different lengths into the same container.

The data changes, and I can see it has changed if I inspect the element, however, I can still see the old data of the container below the loaded data, if I scroll past and back to the position of the new data, it is gone.

I have no source I can post.

I have tried emptying the div first with the following:

```
$("#Container").html("").load('url', function() { });
$("#Container").hide().load('url', function() { }).show();
```

Comment: I assume you one have one #Container in the DOM?

Comment: The `.load()` will empty the container for you. There's something more going on in your code that you're not showing.

Comment: Yeah, only one #Container. I unfortunately choose not to post any code with my question @Bill Criswell, my apologies, and I realize that this makes it incredibly difficult to help in any way, but there is far too much invested to simplify.

Comment: html('') also cleans the container, so there's something else going here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as it turns out, this was a relatively useless question. Although, not entirely. Populating data into my #Container, I did not realize that some of the content was overflowing and exceeding the bounds of the div. When I was loading other content into the #Container, the browser did not resolve the overflow as html in the div and it was still visible. If you load content into a sized div, make sure the div is large enough

Answer (score 1):

You should show/hide elements inside the callback. In your code `show()` may have been executed before `load()` returns any value.

```
$("#Container").html("").load('url', function(response) {
  //take a look  at the structure of response
  var html = stuff(response);
  $(this).html(html);
});
$("#Container").hide().load('url', function(response) {
  $(this).show();
});
```

Hope this helps,

R.